# How I can build table in onpostexecute() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I need to build a table with 1 column and many rows, I am getting data from a server, and then I want to populate this data into the table.

In iOS I can use `UITableVIew`. As I understand, I need to create `gridLayout` on builder and then I need to find it by *id* in the method `onCreate`. Then I need to pass this object to my `Asyncr` class, then I need to get data and build table in the method `onpostexecute`.

Which of the methods I need to use? I want to do simple table like this (but example on iOS) without headers with date

> [image]

**Also i need to do clickable row, if you click on row i need to send you on other activity**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom [ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

In `onPostExecute(Object obj)` parse your data, and set the adapter.

Comment: i need to do something in  activity.xml ?

Comment: Also i need to do clickable row, if you click on row i need to send you on other activity

Comment: Go through the linked tutorial. You need to add ListView in the xml layout file or you can programatically create the ListView.

Comment: Add setOnItemClickListener() to capture list item click